# How to write "Do Until" loop that resizes table?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, resize, dynamic-tables

I'm working with a dynamic table that populates names based on the given weeks data. I have a macro that refreshes and sorts the data as needed but am currently working with the .Resize Range() function to adjust the table based on how the rows populate.

Note: "Login" cells populate based on an IF reference to another sheet: `=IF(WSSW!AH126=0,"-",WSSW!AH126)`

See table ("Table12") itself below (webdings for privacy)
[image: Dynamic Table Problem Area]

Prior to including the loop, `mnTbl.Resize Range("$A$3:" & lcol & lrow - 1)` and `mnTbl.Resize Range("$A$3:" & lcol & lrow + 1)` did exactly what I needed them to. The trouble started when I wanted the macro to decide which operation to run based on the the last cell in my "Login" column. The currently included Do Until loop freezes my application but I left it for current state visibility. The goal is to have the macro decide if it should add a row or remove one.

```
Sub TableDrag()
'
' TableDrag Macro
'

'
Dim MAIN As Worksheet
Set MAIN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN")

Dim mnTbl As ListObject
Set mnTbl = MAIN.ListObjects("Table12")

Dim lrow As String
Dim val As String


' Find Last Row
lcol = "J"
lrow = mnTbl.Range.Rows(mnTbl.Range.Rows.Count).Row
val = Range("A" & lrow).Value

Do Until val <> "-"
    mnTbl.Resize Range("$A$3:" & lcol & lrow - 1)
    Loop



End Sub
```

Comment: Should I even be using a Do Until for this? I'm not very familiar with loops in general, but it seems like I should be able to loop an IF/THEN/ELSE to accomplish the same thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before entering the loop, `val = "-"`. The loop repeats until `val <> "-"`. But the value of `val` is never being changed in the loop. `val` will always be `"-"`, so the loop will never end.

Similar problem with `lrow - 1`. The value of `lrow` is never being changed within the loop. If `lrow = 131` before entering your loop, then every loop will just be `lrow - 1 = 130`.

Whatever condition the loop is testing, the result of that condition should be changed within the loop. In your case, the value of `val` should be changed within the loop. Without modifying your code too much, try:

```
Do Until Val <> "-"
    lrow = lrow - 1
    mnTbl.Resize Range("$A$3:" & lcol & lrow)
    Val = Range("A" & lrow).Value
Loop
```

To clean things up a little, it would be slightly neater to just test the value of `Range("A" & lrow).Value`, and not resize your range until after the loop:

```
Do Until Range("A" & lrow).Value <> "-"
    lrow = lrow - 1
Loop

mnTbl.Resize Range("$A$3:" & lcol & lrow)
```

Comment: This works flawlessly to cut the table down if it's oversized. I flipped the operators in a following loop:
`Do Until Range("A" & lrow).Value = "-"
    lrow = lrow + 1
Loop

mnTbl.Resize Range("$A$3:" & lcol & lrow - 1)`

and it worked like a charm.

apologies for bad formatting

Answer (score 0):

Final Formatting for posterity:

```
    Dim MAIN As Worksheet
    Dim mnTbl As ListObject
    Dim lrow As String
    Dim val As String
    Set MAIN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN")
    Set mnTbl = MAIN.ListObjects("Table12")


'========Resize Table




' Find Last Row

    lcol = "J"
    lrow = mnTbl.Range.Rows(mnTbl.Range.Rows.Count).Row
    val = Range("A" & lrow).Value


' ==Loop through last cell values to resize table

'First operation finds first row in the tables current state 
'containing null value "-" in login column 
'and resizes table to that row minus one

    Do Until Range("A" & lrow).Value <> "-"
        lrow = lrow - 1
    Loop

    mnTbl.Resize Range("$A$3:" & lcol & lrow)


'Second operation extends the table range
'by lrow plus one until the range value
'equals null value of "-"

    Do Until Range("A" & lrow).Value = "-"
        lrow = lrow + 1
        mnTbl.Resize Range("$A$3:" & lcol & lrow)
    Loop

'After loop breaks, resize table by
'removing lrow left over from second operation

    mnTbl.Resize Range("$A$3:" & lcol & lrow - 1)

'Cleanup

'Clear cells below table

    Range("A" & lrow, lcol & lrow + 100).ClearContents
```

Had to put the Resize operation inside the loop for adding rows with another outside the loop that backs it up one row after the loop breaks.

Also added a "cleanup" routine since the main chunk leaves a mess of formulas and formatted cells behind after the resize is complete.

Thanks @kevin for the concise answer and explanation. Really appreciate having the "why" alongside the answer!